# about log(n),how to calculate?

Tags: math

such as:

[image]

equal to:

[image]

What formula using 2 ** x = 11？

Comment: How to calculate what? Using what? Extremely unclear.

Comment: Do you want the algorithm, or do you want to know which library function to use? In what language?

Comment: Exponentiation? Please clarify..

Comment: I want to known, 2**x=11,so how to calculate x's value?

Comment: Then you already have the answers below.

Comment: I want known like math.log function principle:)

Comment: It's too bad this isn't a better formed question as _accurately_ determining ln2(x) _is_ a good programming problem when `double`, `float`, is binary FP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you'd like to know:

**b^x=y**

**x=log(y)/log(b)**

For **b=2** and **y=11** you could write something like this:

**x=log(11)/log(2)**,

where **b** is the logarithm base, whilst **y** is the logarithm argument.

Therefore, you can calculate any logarithm in a programming language by evaluating it to base 10 first, then dividing it by the logarithm of the base, also using the logarithm to base 10.

Here are some examples in various programming languages:

**C#**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplicationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double x = Math.Log10(11) / Math.Log10(2);
            Console.WriteLine("The value of x is {0}.", x);
        }
    }
}
```

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = log10(11)/log10(2);
    cout << "The value of x is " << x << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var x = Math.log(11)/Math.log(2);
document.write("The value of x is "+x+".");
```

Tim has already shown a Python example.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the logarithm of `x` in base `n` is calculated as `log(x)/log(n)`.

Some libraries allow you to take a shortcut. For example, in Python:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log(11)/math.log(2)
3.4594316186372978
>>> math.log(11,2)
3.4594316186372978
>>> 2**_            # _ contains the result of the previous computation
11.000000000000004
```

Comment: I want known math.log function principle

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean? Do you know what a logarithm is? A Taylor series?

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation

Comment: sorry,I don't known math.log() function how to work and that uses what mathematical formula?